# Using different res values in a multi-flavor android library uses wrong values in compiled APK when using gradle caching

Tags: android, gradle

I've discovered an issue in an android project which uses separate library modules. The project uses multiple product flavors and those flavors are reflected in each of the libraries.

One of the libraries uses the `resValue` function to generate different string values based on the flavor.

However, there is an issue that happens when assembling multiple flavors - it seems like the apks generated after the first one get assigned the resource value of the first.

[Here is an example repo that shows the problem](https://github.com/ValCanBuild/AndroidGradleLibFlavorResIssue/tree/main)

Relevant part of App gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    flavorDimensions("environment")

    defaultConfig {
        dimension = "environment"
    }

    productFlavors {
        create("dev")
        create("ppe")
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":testlib"))
}
```

Relevant part of library gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    flavorDimensions("environment")

    defaultConfig {
        dimension = "environment"
    }

    productFlavors {
        create("dev") {
            resValue("string", "aaa_lib_test_gradle", "dev")
        }
        create("ppe") {
            resValue("string", "aaa_lib_test_gradle", "ppe")
        }
    }
}
```

With this configuration if you run `./gradlew clean assemblePpeDebug assembleDevDebug` and inspect the generated dev APK you'll notice that the value of `aaa_lib_test_gradle` is *ppe*, not *dev* as expected.

What is causing this - is there some missing gradle setting I'm not using that I'm supposed to? For reference I am using AGP 7.0.3 and gradle 7.0.2

UPDATE: I found out this only happens when caching is set to true in the gradle properties `org.gradle.caching=true`. Setting it to false produces expected results.

UPDATE 2: This apparently is an issue with AGP 7.x tracked here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/201930057

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this was an issue with older 7.0 versions of AGP. It was addressed in 7.0.4. Can confirm the issue doesn't happen when using that version.

Issues relating to this:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/201930057
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/196852190

Answer (score -1):

I think for that you need to use

```
sourceSets {
    dev {
      res.srcDirs = ['src/dev/res']
    }
}
```

Comment: Where would I add that? In the app gradle file?

Comment: I'm not sure it will change antything. I added 
`sourceSets {
        named("dev") {
            println(res.srcDirs)
        }
    }`

which then prints the directory you mentioned as the console output 

`[../AndroidGradleLibFlavorResIssue/testlib/src/dev/res]`